# Stretch image border uniformly and leave center of image unstretched on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

Is it possible to achieve the same thing on iOS as on Android with this 9-patch file?

[image][image]

Result should be something like this. The flower is something on the background. Then I want to apply the gray overlay with transparent (see through, not stretched) logo in the center.
[image]

(the file is not a valid 9-patch, because of wider patch areas, but that is only for question clarity)

So basically I'd like to overlay the screen with this semi-transparent gray color and in the center would be unstretched logo - kind of cut-off from the overlay. (Notice that logo in image is completely transparent)

I tried to use image slices, but I can't define multiple slices per dimension, so just one border is resizing.

I'd like to avoid tile-ing the background from multiple views.

Comment: why don;t you do it in the simpler way ? Put an image view in a view and let the view be resized as per your requirements .

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I need to "see through the logo" what's behind it. The logo is made of completely transparent pixels. If I draw background colour on one view and logo in another, I wont see through the background.

Comment: you can make the background transparent too. You can also make a certain Rect transparent in the background view.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Please see updated question, I'm not sure we understand each other.